# can anyone explain the default view of top on OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, command-line

There are a lot of fields that are not described in the man page (as far as I can tell anyway).  In particular these 3:

BOOSTS         %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you run man top, under the -o description (sort order), it lists the following short descriptions:

```
          cpu_me CPU time charged to me by other processes.
          cpu_others
                 CPU time charged to other processes by me.
          boosts The number of boosts held by the process.  This is followed by the number of times the process has transitioned from unboosted to  boosted  in brackets.  An asterisk before the value indicates that the process was able to send boosts at some point since the previous update.  For more information about boosts, see xpc_transaction_begin(3).
```

(the other two are self-explanatory, but boost basically refers to the times when a process is making a call that then increases it's run priority temporarily (boosted), and then drops it back down to normal after a period of time (unboosted))

Comment: time charge to other processes and time charged by other processes is not "self-explanatory".  How do processes charge other processes?